# Fixed effects with unbalanced panel

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I'm trying to use R to run a fixed effect model on panel data, I have a dataset of 29 countries observed on 22 years, my dependent variable and and 6 independent variables.
I have some missing observations for some years.
When I perform the fixed effect model this is that I have:

[image]

Why don't I have any values for the r-squared and F-stat?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Only 9 (usable) observations are in your data set (see the summary output `N = 9`). This is quiet a small data set. At the same time, you estimate 6 coefficients. These consume degrees of freedom and there are not enough degrees of freedom left for the test statistics to be calculated properly.

You mentioned adj. R-sqr and F test but you missed that you also do not have appropriate estimates for the standard errors (see column `Std. Error` which has `Inf`, hence column `t-value` is 0 and p-value is `NA` for all coefficients.

So, you might want to increase your data or estimate less coefficients (change your model). However, I wonder whether having only 9 observations could be useful for any inference at all.